# Cordova - Broadcast intent to pick up an image

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I would simply like to broadcast an intent to pick up an image on my Android Cordova app. I found [this plugin](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) which supposedly does the job. This is how I am trying it :

```
   MLB.load_img = function() {
    window.plugins.webintent.sendBroadcast({
        action: 'android.intent.action.PICK',
        extras: {
        }
      }, 
      function(success) {
        console.log(success);
      }, 
      function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  };
```

This does nothing except calling the first callback. 
Am I missing something obvious or is there no documentation at all in Cordova's world ? Is there any way to do it, although it doesn't seem documented any where ?

Any suggestion is most welcome